# SOAP Request in PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, xmlhttprequest

Good morning everybody,

I searched this website for a helpful response for integrating a SOAP Request in PHP, but I didn't find anything that solved my problem.

I'm new to SOAP and can't figure out why I receive following error message as response:

object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["CU_Check_BalanceResult"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["error"]=> string(20) "Wrong Authentication" } }

This is my PHP Script:

```
<?php

/* Initialize webservice with your WSDL */
$client = new SoapClient("https://loyalty.brain-behind.com/CU_WebAPI.asmx?wsdl");

class CU_Check_Balance{
    public $provider,
    $password,
    $CardID,
    $TerminalID;
    }

$parameters = new CU_Check_Balance();
$parameters->provider = "string";
$parameters->password = "string";
$parameters->CardID = "string";
$parameters->TerminalID = "string";

$response = $client->CU_Check_Balance($parameters);

var_dump($response);

?>
```

The corresponding WSDL can be found here:

http://loyalty.brain-behind.com/CU_WebAPI.asmx?wsdl

I also tried to implement it in JS, but that didn't work either.

I also installed SOAP UI, made a test project with this wsdl and it worked fine.

This is the example request I got with SOAP UI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:loy="https://loyalty.brain-behind.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <loy:AuthSoapHd3>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <!--type: string-->

         <!--Optional:-->
         <!--type: string-->
         <loy:provider>string</loy:provider><loy:password>string</loy:password>
      </loy:AuthSoapHd3>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <loy:CU_Check_Balance>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <!--type: string-->

         <!--Optional:-->
         <!--type: string-->
         <loy:CardID>string</loy:CardID><loy:TerminalID>string</loy:TerminalID>
      </loy:CU_Check_Balance>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please could somebody help me to get this thing working in php.

Comment: Presumably, since the error states `Wrong Authentication`, one of your parameters is incorrect. Double-check your values (assuming you've used `"string"` instead of the real ones). If there is any API documentation, check that. If access is paid for, contact the website support.

Comment: I just added the "string" because I didn't want to hand out my user/pwd on the internet. I checked the values again, and they are correct - is there any possibility that I show the request that my php script produces?

P.S.: Thanks for the really fast reply

Comment: Very wise :) Try using `var_dump($client->__getLastRequest())`. Note you will also need to enable the `trace` option when instantiating the soap client. See the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) for more details.

Comment: I added the trace flag and got some output, but it doesn't make sense to me => new client call `code`$client = new SoapClient("https://loyalty.brain-behind.com/CU_WebAPI.asmx?wsdl",array('trace' => 1));`code` and the output - I added the ====request==== and ====response==== to see where my request ends and the response begins: ====Request==== string(340) " 31320000002036012345678 " ====Response==== object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["CU_Check_BalanceResult"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["error"]=> string(20) "Wrong Authentication" } } - Shouldn't the Request be like my example request mentioned above?

Comment: According to the manual page the return value should be an XML string.  I'm behind my company firewall so I can't test this for you directly.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get an open connection and tried your code (as posted) and see exactly the same error. Using `var_dump($client);` as the last line gives me all the expected output.  The last request value looks like a correct SOAP request (but with wrong params): `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://loyalty.brain-behind.com"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:CU_Check_Balance><ns1:CardID>string</ns1:CardID><ns1:TerminalID>string</ns1:TerminalID></ns1:CU_Check_Balance></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`

Comment: Got my Problem - echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()) . "\n"; - now my request is xml formatted - but half of it is missing => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://loyalty.brain-behind.com"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:CU_Check_Balance><ns1:CardID>313200000020360</ns1:CardID><ns1:TerminalID>12345678</ns1:TerminalID></ns1:CU_Check_Balance></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope> -- the whole Authentication part isn't there as in my sample request from SOAP UI and I don't get it why.

Comment: I tried it with the right Params, but the first part of the request seems missing - the whole Authentication part is skipped and doesn't appear - [link]http://loyalty.brain-behind.com/CU_WebAPI.asmx?op=CU_Check_Balance[/link] got a sample request mentioned and I got no idea how to get the authentication infos into my request.

Comment: Please close the topic - I simply forgot to initialize the header for the authentication part - feeling a little bit stupid right now

Comment: Please, can you add here the initialization process for that authentication part? I am solving the same problem right now but don't know how..

Answer (score 0):

I have been solving this question too, hope this can help, this is workable solution with brain-behind.com. Two variants - test and production credentials.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Prague');

//*
$wsdl = "https://loyalty.brain-behind.com/CU_WebAPI.asmx?wsdl";
/*/
$wsdl = "https://testo.brain-behind.com/CU_WebAPI.asmx?wsdl"; //for your testing credentials, change only this $wsdl address, not $location
//*/
$location = "https://loyalty.brain-behind.com";

$provider = "TESTBB|1111";
$password = "abcdefghijkl";
$cardId = '111111111111111';
$terminalId = 'AA111111';

$login = new stdClass();
$login->provider = $provider;
$login->password = $password;

$params = new stdClass();
$params->CardID = $cardId;
$params->TerminalID = $terminalId;

$dump = array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//*
$soap = new SoapClient($wsdl);
/*/
$soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $dump); // trace ON, then print LastRequest, LastResponse, LastRequestHeaders
//*/

//var_dump($soap->__getFunctions());
//var_dump($soap->__getTypes());


$header = new SoapHeader($location, 'AuthSoapHd3', $login);
$soap->__setSoapHeaders($header);


try {
    // check balance
    $response = $soap->CU_Check_Balance($params);
    var_dump($response);

    //////////////////////////////////////

    $count = 2;
    $ticketPrice = 28;
    $cashback = 2; //cashback per ticket
    $params->PurchaseDate = date('c'); //UTF format
    $params->PurchaseAmount = $count * $ticketPrice; // in Euros
    $params->BonusAmount = $count * $cashback * 100; // in Eurocents
    $params->Encryption='';

    // add kredit to account
    $response = $soap->CU_Add_Bonus($params);
    var_dump($response);
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo 'Exception:<br>';
    print_r($exc->getTrace());
}

echo '<br><br>LastRequest:';
var_dump($soap->__getLastRequest());
echo '<br><br>LastResponse:';
var_dump($soap->__getLastResponse());
echo '<br><br>LastHeaders:';
var_dump($soap->__getLastRequestHeaders());
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.